# How can you set a user collection attribute to an array of objects in meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

We're using collection2 (obviously with simple schema) and trying to save an array of objects to a single property on the Meteor.users collection.  For example our data might be:

```
[
    {name: "paul"},
    {name: "darryn"},
    {name: "tom"}
]
```

*in reality our object is more complex*

when trying to do this with `$set` in an update on the users collection we've either gotten 500's or managed to delete the user object entirely when turning off validation.

we've also gotten the following error a number of times:

`Validation object must have at least one operator / meteor mongo`

[This StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566429/validation-object-must-have-at-least-one-operator-meteor-mongo) mentions it but doesn't offer a solution that makes sense in our context.

My question is two fold.  How should the schema be defined for this as we've been trying with `type: [Object]` which I'm not sure is right, and secondly how should the update statement be created in the method.

Any thoughts, or help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define the schema for your *complex* object. Here I've just added *age* as a key:

```
Schema.Foo = new SimpleSchema({
  name: { type: String },
  age: { type: Number, min: 0 }
});
```

Then augment the user schema with a key whose type is *an array of the type you just defined*

```
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
  foo: { type: [Schema.foo] },
  etc...
});
```